# How can I iterate from a specific Excel cell to the latest row having a value in this column using VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I am absolutly new in Excel and **VBA** macro and I have the following problem.

I wrote this code that print the content of the **K** column cell starting from the 3th row to the 5th row:

```
Dim outQuantityRange As Range
Set outQuantityRange = Range("K3:K5")


For Each currentOutQuantity In outQuantityRange.Cells
    MsgBox (currentOutQuantity)
```

It works fine. My problem is that I want change this code to access to the content of the cell into the **K** column starting from the 3th row and ending to the last inserted value. For example if the last value is into the **K100** cell it have to print the content of: **K3, K4, K5,......,K100**.

I don't want to specify **K100** but it have to stop to the last row having a value into the K column.

How can I implement this behavior?
        Next

Comment: Are the entries in column **K** constants for formulas??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error in finding last used cell in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are no gaps between K3 and last row, then this will do the work:

```
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("K3", Range("K3").End(xlDown))
```

Comment: Using `xlDown` will return `$K$3:$K$1048576` if `K3` has the only value in the column.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook These are all "guess games".

Comment: I've no idea what that means.

Answer (score 1):

I've given two ways to find the last cell - using the `LastCell` function will return the very last cell on the sheet which may not be in column K.

The second way I've shown is just finding the last cell in column K.

The range is then set by giving the first and last cell references separated by a comma.

```
Sub AllValues()

    Dim outQuantityRange As Range
    Dim currentOutQuantity As Range
    Dim rLastCell As Range

    With ThisWorkbook

        'Find last cell on sheet containing data.
        'Set rLastCell = LastCell(.Worksheets("MySheetName"))

        With .Worksheets("MySheetName")
            'Find last cell in column K containing data.
            Set rLastCell = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 11).End(xlUp)
            Set outQuantityRange = .Range("K3", rLastCell)
        End With
    End With

    For Each currentOutQuantity In outQuantityRange
        MsgBox currentOutQuantity, vbOKOnly + vbInformation
    Next currentOutQuantity

End Sub

Public Function LastCell(wrkSht As Worksheet) As Range

    Dim lLastCol As Long, lLastRow As Long

    On Error Resume Next

    With wrkSht
        lLastCol = .Cells.Find("*", , , , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Column
        lLastRow = .Cells.Find("*", , , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row

        If lLastCol = 0 Then lLastCol = 1
        If lLastRow = 0 Then lLastRow = 1

        Set LastCell = wrkSht.Cells(lLastRow, lLastCol)
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

If the values in column **K** are constants, then:

```
Sub qwerty()
    Dim outQuantityRange As Range, zell As Range

    Set outQuantityRange = Range("K3:K" & Rows.Count).SpecialCells(2)

    For Each zell In outQuantityRange.Cells
        MsgBox zell.Value
    Next zell
End Sub
```